# SQL Delete duplicates - Keep Deleted IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I need to find and delete duplicates from within a table, yet keep a record of the IDs of the records being deleted and add them to a 'deleted_ids' field.

For example, here's part of a table I have currently:

```
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Id     | Name                                                  |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|   9627 |  John Smith                                           |
|   9657 |  John Smith                                           |
|  24455 |  John Smith                                           |
|  67435 |  John Smith                                           |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

The result I'd like to achieve is:

```
+--------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+
| Id     | Name                        | Deleted_Ids             |
+--------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+
|   9627 |  John Smith                 | 9657,24455,67435        |
+--------+-----------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I'm open to any practical approach, if anyone can provide a solution or give suggestions I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: What do you need the list of deleted items for? Have you considered using "logical delete" instead of "physical delete"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you want to proceed like this, here is a simple way.
Do it all **in one transaction** to be sure.
If there could be an entry of `'John Smith'` in `tbl_del` already, you have to check and `UPDATE` to add the deleted ids instead.

```
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO tbl_del
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS deleted
FROM   tbl_live
WHERE  name = 'John Smith'
GROUP  BY 1;

DELETE FROM tbl_live
WHERE  name = 'John Smith';

COMMIT;
```

But I think Veseliq has a vaid point.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do it with another column - storing IDs as comma separated list doesn't feel right, does it?

Best would be to have a second table with two columns PrimaryUserId and DeletedUserId - the PrimaryUserId would be "9627" for example - the one of the record you actually keep and you will add a row for every duplicate you delete from your main table. This approach would also allow for you to store a column that knows when the duplicate entry was deleted.

Comment: I thought about that, if a sensible solution for that pops up I'll consider it. The only issue is I'm dealing with 200mm rows - and the deleted_ids will very rarely be accessed. So the comma separated approach would be the ideal for storage reasons.

Comment: @Paul: This is best. You can modify Erwin's transaction for this approach.

Comment: The difference in storage would be minimal.

Comment: I can not agree. 200 million rows are not such a problem in database made purely of integers. Especially if you don't consider accessing them all the time. And you would know it, because if the second table requires to take up 200 million rows, then the main table takes much more traffic. In fact if you go with the comma separated values, you sacrifice performance - you will be doing expensive selects + updates on your main table instead of doing inserts on table that there is no problem to lock, reindex, etc

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach can be to first select all rows from old table, that qualifies the deletion criteria ->
Insert these rows into new table ->
delete all rows from old table

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT id,name FROM old_table WHERE id > 
(
  SELECT min(id) FROM old_table B
  WHERE A.name = B.name
);

delete FROM old_table WHERE id > 
(
  SELECT min(id) FROM old_table B
  WHERE A.name = B.name
);
```

you can have auto incremented key in new table.
I have not run these queries, pardon me if here are some errors, thats just for an idea. 
Having one to many relationship within these two tables can really be handy in future....and easier to query the data